# How do I make react-pdf render a pdf for dark mode?

Tags: reactjs, styling, darkmode, react-pdf

Is there a way to configure [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf/v/7.5.1) to support dark mode? The only configuration I found was to change the `canvasBackground`, but the text and tables with striped rows needs to change color also.

I've also tried customTextRenderer, but that only takes a function that returns a string.

Comment: https://react-pdf.org/styling ?

Comment: @KJ I suggest removing your comments as they are not related to the question (and my comment was not directed at you). tuanvu If styling will help you, you may want to close this question, as you might not have [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking, and you could open a more focused question, or if you can add a reproducible example for how the style is not working on tables, that might help get a focused answer.